# bash script replace only match and start special IP address?

Tags: regex, sed

Can you please help me bash script?
i need use only start and match iP address. for example

```
Y8.78.94 488752   X1.188 36582   62.111.101.260 #S 
Y8.62.111 5789544 X1.132 5364789 8.8.4.4 #S
```

but when i use this command

```
> sed -i 's/62.111./Z./g' test.txt
```

But the result it change all like as:

```
Y8.78.94 488752   X1.188 36582   Z.101.260 #S 
Y8.Z. 5789544 X1.132 5364789 8.8.4.4 #S
```

`Y8.Z.` it is wrong we should be not changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regular expression, `.` matches any character. So `62.111.` matches `62.111` followed by space at the beginning.

You should match the `.` literally by escaping it.

```
sed -i 's/62\.111\./Z./g' test.txt
```